# Global hook take effects when the API is called for the second time

Tags: dll, hook

All

I have implemented a global Windows hook to hook the API `MessageBox()`, the hook is implemented in a dll, when I setup the windows hook in a win32 console application (with the dll loaded) and call `MessageBox()`, the API is successfully hooked. For brevity, I name this win32 application EXE1.

Since I set up a global hook, I also want the calls to `MessageBox()` by other applications also be hooked. Therefore, I run another win32 console application -- EXE2 (with EXE1 running at the same time), which calls `MessageBox()` for three times. However, the first call is not hooked. I don't know why. (The code is in ansi format.) The codes are as follows:

-----------------------dll--------------------------------------------

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT        // Allow use of features specific to Windows XP or later.                   
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif                      

//for the getaddrinfo test
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32")

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mhook.h"

//=========================================================================
// Define _MessageBox so we can dynamically bind to the function
typedef int (WINAPI* _MessageBox) (HWND, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, UINT);

//=========================================================================
// Get the current (original) address to the functions to be hooked
//
_MessageBox TrueMessageBox = (_MessageBox)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"user32"), "MessageBoxW");


//=========================================================================
// This is the function that will replace MessageBox once the hook
// is in place
MMRESULT WINAPI HookMessageBoxW(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR  lpText, LPCTSTR  lpCaption, UINT uType){
    printf("***** Call to MessageBox\n");
    lpText = L"hooked MessageBox";
    // Call the original waveInOpen function
    MMRESULT nResult = TrueMessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
    return nResult;
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:YCIShared,RWS")
#pragma data_seg("YCIShared")
HHOOK g_hHook = NULL;
#pragma data_seg()

HMODULE hInstance = 0;

static LRESULT WINAPI GetMsgProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{   printf("=======\n");
    //Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&TrueMessageBox, HookMessageBoxW);
    return ::CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL WINAPI SetSysHook(BOOL bInstall, DWORD dwThreadId)
{
    BOOL bOk;
    if(bInstall) 
    {
        g_hHook = ::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgProc, 
                        hInstance, dwThreadId);
        bOk = (g_hHook != NULL);
    } 
    else 
    {
        bOk = ::UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hHook);
        g_hHook = NULL;
    }
    return bOk;
}




BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        hInstance = (HINSTANCE) hModule;
        printf("dll loaded!============================\n");
        if(Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&TrueMessageBox, HookMessageBoxW)) //hook
            printf("MessageBox Hook Succeeded!\n");
        else
            printf("MessageBox Hook Failed");


        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        Mhook_Unhook((PVOID*)&TrueMessageBox);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

-------------------------------end of dll---------------------------------------------
You cannot build this dll because it calls a self-implemented function `Mhook_SetHook()` and `Mhook_Unhook()`, which are from **mhook**. The DLL file is named as **mhook-2.3-dll.dll**.

------------------------------EXE1---------------------------------------------------

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT        // Allow use of features specific to Windows XP or later.                   
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif                      

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mhook-2.3-dll.lib")

extern "C"  _declspec(dllimport) BOOL WINAPI SetSysHook(BOOL bInstall, DWORD dwThreadId);

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
    //HMODULE hModule = ::LoadLibrary(L"mhook-2.3-dll.dll");
    SetSysHook(TRUE, 0);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, (LPCTSTR)L"MessageBox", NULL, MB_OK);          //hooked
    SetSysHook(FALSE, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

--------------------------------end of EXE1-----------------------------------------

--------------------------------EXE2------------------------------------------------
    #include 
    #include

```
int main(){

    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)L"MessageBox1", NULL, MB_OK);      //not hooked
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)L"MessageBox2", NULL, MB_OK);      //hooked
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)L"MessageBox3", NULL, MB_OK);      //hooked
    return 0;
}
```

-------------------------------end of EXE2------------------------------------------

Comment: Your test code does not call GetMessage() until *after* the first call to MessageBox().  It is the message box that calls it.  You'll need to call Mhook_SetHook() in DllMain().

Comment: I did this, I called Mhook_SetHook() in DllMain() once the dll is loaded. I don't under stand why yuou mention the GetMessage(), I did not intend to call it in my tests. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you used a WH_GETMESSAGE hook.  The hook callback isn't going to run until somebody calls GetMessage().

Comment: But in EXE1, I only call MessageBox() once, there is no prior call to GetMessage(), then why MessageBox() is hooked?

Comment: You call MessageBoxA() in EXE2

Comment: Well, if I run EXE1 alone, MessageBox() will also be hooked.